# Flag setting using query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i set flag 1,2 and 3 for every rows using sql query? By ordering date field either des/asc

Your help is highly appreciated.

For eg:

```
    Id      Name        date        flag
    9278    david       02/12/2012  1
    4343    sharon      21/11/2012  2
    4783    elizabeth   17/11/2012  3
    47846   john        08/10/2012  1
    78347   chris       17/09/2012  2
    37379   Joe         18/06/2012  3
```

Comment: How are you determining what needs to be 1,2 or 3?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as there is no way you can rank these records in the way you described in your example. Please provide a correct example so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you might need to use a combination of the ROW_NUMBER function and the modulo operator:

```
with temp as
(
    select 9278 as num,    'david' as name,       CONVERT( datetime, '02/12/12',3) as date
    UNION
    select 4343,    'sharon',      CONVERT( datetime, '21/11/12',3)
    UNION
    select 4783,    'elizabeth',   CONVERT( datetime, '17/11/12',3)
    UNION
    select 47846,   'john',        CONVERT( datetime, '08/10/12',3)
    UNION
    select 78347,   'chris' ,      CONVERT( datetime, '17/09/12',3)
    UNION
    select 37379,   'Joe' ,        CONVERT( datetime, '18/06/12',3)
)

select *, 
       ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date desc) + 2) % 3) + 1  as Flag 
from temp
```

If this data is being consumed by some programming language I would probably try to add the number there instead of in the SQL Code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's sql2008:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) as Flag from YourTable
```

Comment: OK, now you've changed the question, so answer is not valid any more.

Comment: @Oded reformatted the question but the content has not changed (though it is at least readable now...)  Either way, I do not think this will work.

Comment: Yes, it was difficult to read and by checking just first three records I wrongly assumed he need consecutive sequence.

Comment: Definitely a confusing question.